# How do you retrieve records and all child records in one database hit in ADO.NET Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I would like to make one database call to retrieve the following data, but I'm struggling to figure out what the LINQ should look like. Here's my current implementation (I know it's bad!!):

```
var photos = from photo in entitiesContext.Photo
             join pg in entitiesContext.PhotoGallery on photo.PhotoGallery.PhotoGalleryID equals pg.PhotoGalleryID
             where pg.PhotoGallery == photoGalleryID
             select photo;

var photoList = photos.ToList();

foreach (var photoForLoading in photoList)
{
    photoForLoading.UserReference.Load();
    photoForLoading.PhotoComments.Load();

    foreach (var comment in photoForLoading.PhotoComment)
    {
        comment.UserReference.Load();
    }
}

return photoList;
```

So as you can see above I want to retrieve:

- All the photos from a specific photo gallery:

  - The user details on each photo
  - The comments on each photo

    - The user details on each comment

How do I do this in LINQ with ADO.NET Entities Framework?

Cheers,
Ash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the .Include method to load the related entities. For example:

```
from photo in entitiesContext.Photo
                          .Include("UserReference")
                          .Include("PhotoComments")
etc...
```

Comment: I assume this will result in one SQL statement (with a couple inner joins) sent to the SQL server? Also the photos may not contain any comments, would I need to do some form of a left outer join?

Comment: No if there is a comment you will have a value, if there is no comment you would get NULL. Check for nulls should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

When creating your ObjectQuery, call the **Include** method, passing in the name of the subentity that you want to load automatically.  You can chain calls to Include if you have multiple subentities that you want to load.

See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx) for more information.